# Getting error during Salesforce integration in PHP

Tags: php, salesforce, apex-code

I'm getting this error `" Ooop! Error: Element {}item invalid at this location "` at the time of calling Salesforce web service in PHP.

Bellow are my approaches:

```
require_once('salesforceAPI/soapclient/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
require_once('salesforceAPI/soapclient/SforceHeaderOptions.php');

$sfdc = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
$SoapClient = $sfdc->createConnection('enterprise.wsdl.xml');

$loginResult = false;

$loginResult = $sfdc->login(USER, PASSWORD . SECURITY_KEY);

$parsedURL = parse_url($sfdc->getLocation());
define("_SFDC_SERVER_", substr($parsedURL['host'], 0, strpos($parsedURL['host'], '.')));
define("_WS_NAME_", 'salesforceAPI/Ctest');
define("_WS_WSDL_", _WS_NAME_ . '.xml');
define("_WS_ENDPOINT_", 'https://' . _SFDC_SERVER_ . '.salesforce.com/services/wsdl/class/' . _WS_NAME_);
define("_WS_NAMESPACE_", 'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/' . _WS_NAME_);

$client = new SoapClient(_WS_WSDL_);
$sforce_header = new SoapHeader(_WS_NAMESPACE_, "SessionHeader", array("sessionId" => $sfdc->getSessionId()));
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($sforce_header));

$method = $client->__getFunctions();

$wsParams = array('accName' => 'dasarathi');

$client->cInsert($wsParams);
```

I have no clue for solution.

Answer (score 1):

It was a file path issue. Below is the rectification:

```
define("_WS_NAME_", 'salesforceAPI/Ctest');

// there is no such path http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/slesforceAPI/Ctest
define("_WS_NAMESPACE_", 'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/' . _WS_NAME_);
```

I just redeclared the *WS_NAME* constant:

```
define("_WS_NAME_", 'Ctest');
```